# Bounded transformation gives first moment: $E h(X) < \infty?$

Tags: probability

If $X$ has moment, and $h$ is a transformation which is bounded by an affine function $a + b|x|$, does $h(X)$ have first moment?

$\int |h| X \ d P \le \int (a + b|x|) X \ dP  .... ?$

Comment: isnt first moment $\int |h(X)|dP$ not $\int |h|XdP$? So its just linearity of the integral.